# Is there a way to get an auto-formatter to preserve monadic code style?

Tags: ocaml, code-formatting

For Monadic-style OCaml code like this:

```
let program =
    let ( >>= ) m f = bind m f in
    get >>= fun s ->
    put (s + 1) >>= fun _ ->
    get >>= fun x ->
    return (x + 3)
```

Is there a way to get a code formatter to preserve the style of keeping the `fun`s on the right?

When I use `ocamlformat`, it does this:

```
let program =
    let ( >>= ) m f = bind m f in
    get >>= fun s -> put (s + 1) >>= fun _ -> get >>= fun x -> return (x + 3)
```

> [binding operators](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual046.html) would look a lot nicer than `>>=`, but I can't use them yet.